# [Meta] Did our site make the cut for StackExchange 2.0?

Tags: meta

I'm going to keep posting questions and answers here no matter what, but are we defined as an "Active" site or not under StackExchange's new rules?

Answer (score 3):

We are not defined as "active" in terms of having 1 year before moving to the new system. So this site, at the latest, will be moved over to 2.0 within 3 months.

However, [Taylor](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/users/3/taylor) and I are excited for this, and might even be willing to migrate over even sooner, if possible.

Considering how many IT / developer related people also homebrew, we both feel that BrewAdvice will have no issue staying alive when it comes to a [StackOverflow.com](http://stackoverflow.com) vote. I think we have almost a dozen active users on here who write code or do something in that field.

I think Taylor is going to contact [Rich](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/users/170/rich-armstrong) or someone else at [SE](http://stackexchange.com) to discuss this in further.

We'll make sure this site stays around even if we don't make the cut.

Please, continue to ask more questions as you have them, both about beer and about BrewAdvice!

Comment: I have been wondering how many visitors there really are, because things have seemed to slow down over the past 4-8weeks.

Comment: I can give you the actual analytics if you want. But ya, it has slowed down a bit. I had some extra google ad word credits from GoDaddy, so I had those pushing traffic for a little bit too.

Comment: Dashboard 1/1/10 - 4/14/10 http://skitch.com/hookedonwinter/n6hn1/dashboard-google-analytics

Comment: Dashboard 1/1/10 - 4/14/10 - overall stats - http://skitch.com/hookedonwinter/n6hn1/dashboard-google-analytics

Comment: General Traffic Sources 1/1/10 - 4/14/10 - http://skitch.com/hookedonwinter/n6hn2/traffic-sources-overview-google-analytics

Comment: If you want to see any other stats, let me know

Comment: Thanks for the info.

Comment: @brewchez:
Sorry, but I think I joined about 4-8 weeks ago.  Did I forget to brush my teeth or something? :)

Answer (score 2):

Just FYI (and not sure where else to put it), Stack Exchange launched their site launching site (repeat words much PJ?) at [area51.stackexchange.com](http://area51.stackexchange.com). The beer community site is being discussed here: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/1619/homebrewing-beer-wine-etc

Please go give your input over there. I'd love for this community to help shape the future of this site.

Comment: I registered and started adding questions/commenting - but, what is this exactly? If this proposal is accepted, what are the ramifications for brewadvice?